# Filter Global Search

Tags: aura, global-search

Is there a way to filter Global Search without having to do magic with Sharing Rules and Record Types?

I want a CSR to search Contacts, but I don't want the CSR to see the Contact come up in a search. My sharing settings on Contact is "controlled by parent", and I'd like to keep it that way due to the rest of the data model depends on it. Is there a way to use the Aura "backgroundUtilityItem" to somehow hijack the search or some other custom way?

Comment: why don't you want the CSR to see Contacts? If there's data on the search result (i.e. fields) that you want to hide, then make them not viz via FLS

Comment: The reason is the VIP status of the contact. Hiding the fields via FLS is fine, but would like to avoid special training to a CSR that when they search for a record and if they land on this one, then they'll have to try other ones to get the info they need.